# Computer doesn´t recognize MKR1010

Tags: usb, mkr1010

I´m learning how to use the Arduino MKR1010. When I wrote a program for controlling LEDs and to read a BMP280 sensor with a web aplication, and I uploaded the program to the board, suddenly the computer did not recognice the board.

The power LED of the board works, but I can't access the board with my computer, and I can't see in the COM ports list, and neither as a "unrecognised device" to reinstall the drivers.

I have tried with a few others USB cables and with another computer, but I still have the same problem. I have also tried to press the reset button reset and I still have the same result. What can I do to make my board work?

Answer (score 0):

The MKR board connects to computer over native USB support of the MCU. The handling of the USB is done by Arduino core functions linked at build to your sketch.

A consequence of using the native USB port is, if your sketch has a problem, it influences the USB communication. In this case you can activate the bootloader to handle the USB port and the upload. It is done by **double clicking the reset button on board**.

This applies to other SAMD boards (Zero, M0) and to AVR boards with native USB port (Leonardo, Micro) too.

Comment: I followed these steps, I connected the board to the computer, the power led is on and the chrd led is on for a few seconds, I press the board button reset two times and the board doesn't do anything. It's possible that the board it's broken?

Comment: @mourazo, the onboard LED should start blinking with slow fade.

Comment: It  start blinking for a few seconds at the start, later it´s off and i can´t do anything with the board